# Confluence export dynamic PDF title

Tags: pdf-generation, confluence

I am using Confluence 4.0.3, I am trying to create a PDF layout/stylesheet so that it would grab the main title from the page content and move it to the title page.

What I have tried so far:

1. use the way that confluence suggests - it did not work well at all because it came with extra toc (np, I can hide it) and extra page content because it requires me to export from the parent level for it to work
2. I define a macro which contains the page title and I can use css to make it land on the title page. This works however if I was to export multiple docs this could pose a issue
3. Style the h1:first-child, this works but again on multiple docs this would be an issue.

Question: Is there a good way to do this on multiple doc exports? If not, does the page title have its own class that I can target instead of the h1:first-child? I tried h1.pagetitle (in their documentation) but it does not work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a user defined macro to put the title in and use the PDF export css to position it on the title page. This works as long as you are only exporting 1 document at the exporting level. If you are exporting 2 or more docs from the same exporting level then you can only define 1 of the macros or else they will all be at the same position on the title page.

This seems like the easiest way I found to implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try employing a minor work-around. You could use a .asp page, which is located off of confluence, to pull the the pdf title and display it how you like. Then you can use an html-include macro to display the .asp page, and the pdf title it shows, wherever you like on confluence.

Comment: we are on a java server, but no worries, I used a user defined macro to incude the title of the title page, and use the pdf export css to position it on the title page. Down fall to this is that this only works if you are exporting 1 document of that architecture level. If you are exporting 2 docs from the same level then you need to define only 1 macro on one of the pages